# Visual Studio: What's the correct way to reference resources across projects?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, resources

**An .xaml image location in a secondary reference is not becoming the correct resource location during runtime, it refers to the primary reference resources folder instead. How can I change this?**

Background -

I have a solution with several projects. The important three projects here are

1. a WPF project which builds as a class library
2. a default class 
   library
3. a console app for testing

The WPF project has a .png image in its resources. In the MainWindow created it's called via:

```
<ImageBrush
  ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/MyDemoImage.png" 
  Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

When I run an instance of the WPF window directly through the `console app`, it works fine. The resource reference becomes during runtime:

`C:\Users\me.me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\sol\
WPFProjectName\
bin\Resources\MyDemoImage.png`

But if I create a reference to the WPF project within the class library project then call an instance of the class library, the address becomes

`C:\Users\me.me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\sol\
ClassLibraryName\
bin\Resources\MyDemoImage.png`

So this "pack" address becomes a reference to the class library resources rather than the WPF project resources folder.

Now, I think I could simply add the resource to that middle-man class library too, but I'm wondering if there's some correct way to reference a "secondary" resource, so I only have to add images once?

By the way, the error I get when I try to compile this is `System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkup` - I've found answers regarding this but tried what they say to no avail (mark image as copy always etc.)

Comment: The image file should be an assembly resource and accessed by a [Referenced Assembly Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris), i.e. `pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/MyDemoImage.png`, where `AssemblyName` is replaced by the actual name of the assembly that contains the file.

Comment: Excellent, I'll give this a shot. I actually found a *solution* by changing the `BuildAction` to `Embedded Resource` but now when I reference this assembly in another application (i.e. Excel VBA) the address has changed to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 15 etc... I hope your fix fixes it :D

Answer (score 0):

Change

`pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/MyDemoImage.png`

to

`pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/MyDemoImage.png`

**Thanks to @Clemens for his advice. This worked great.**

I just wanted to answer and share a bit of other frustration-gathered knowledge I found while experimenting with this.

Using `pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/MyDemoImage.png` worked great for me for my first image. I then had loads of trouble trying to do the same thing for a 2nd/ 3rd image. It kept compiling ok but on runtime the inner exceptions were throwing out that it couldn't find "resources/mydemoimage.png"

The reason for this was due to the **BuildAction** on the images. I'd been playing with the different types, some of which worked for my local copy (e.g. setting **BuildAction** to `Embedded Resource` actually fixed the initial issue I was having) BUT for the `pack://app...` to work, compile and then carry through to install and be instanced in another application (e.g. VBA in Excel)...

The **BuildAction** *MUST* be `Resource`

I was *extremely* lucky that I'd set this by chance before trying Clemens' answer because if I hadn't I would have assumed it just didn't work! But it does!